# MVC3 Razor custom templates for primitive types and downcasting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, templates, razor, casting

I've got a view model as:

```
public class AttributeEditorViewModel
{
    public long AttributeId { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

The model is build using a model builder so that a final view model has a list of above objects:

```
public class AttributeListViewModel
{
    public List<AttributeEditorViewModel> Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

My model builder compiled a list of AttributeEditorViewModel object and sets appropriate primitive type to the Value property. The data type comes from separate definitions of attributes.

Now the Razor view (lets say edit.cshtml) looks something like:

```
@model AttributeListViewModel

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Attributes)
```

and the editor template Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/AttributeEditorViewModel.cshtml:

```
@model AttributeEditorViewModel

<div>
    <label>@Model.DisplayName</label>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Value)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Value)
</div>
```

What I would expect; If I set the Value property of a AttributeEditorViewModel to a double, like so:

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    return View(new AttributeListViewModel 
    {
        Attributes = new List<AttributeEditorViewModel> 
        {
            new AttributeEditorViewModel { DisplayName = "Double example", Value = (double) 0 }
        }
    };
}
```

I would expect that a text box would be rendered. Instead it renders nothing. I've added another editor template Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Double.cshtml:

```
@model double

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m)
```

Which solved the immediate problem. So now I get a textbox with value 0 in it. However using the EditorFor even inside the custom editor template again renders nothing.

Is it fundamentally wrong to use object as base type for this? Why is it rendering nothing when EditorFor or EditorForModel is used?

Any insight appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. While all the answers explain a lot, it was the hint about compile time bindings used that made most sense. It is a bit counter intuitive though. One would expect run time to decide which editor to use depending on what the "actual" type of the value was. Anyway, I've since added a new property TypeName to the model which literally specifies which editor to use. It's up to me to create all editor templates for possible type names. I also found it helpful when I had to do a custom model binder to read these values back correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because EditorFor uses compile-time binding on the generic parameters to determine which template to render.

And since there's no `EditorFor<object>()` defined by default, you get nothing.

I believe you can define your own editor template for object if you want, but probably a better way would be to make your view model generic:

```
public class AttributeEditorViewModel<TValue>
{
    public long AttributeId { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public TValue Value { get; set; }
}
```

However, this might not be ideal as you could no longer have a list of polymorphic view models.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with object and editor for is exactly what do you want it to do, imagine it contained a dictionary of 2,000,000 DataTables each containing 300 columns and 20,000 rows.  What should it display exactly?  There is nothing intrinsically wrong with using a property of type object on your model just don't expect Razor to magically know what kind of editor it should display based on what you stick in the object.

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem lies in your Razor view code.  When you do:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Attributes)
```

You're telling the view engine to look for an `EditFor` template for `List<AttributeEditorViewModel>` **not for** `AttributeEditorViewModel`.  So it uses the default `ObjectTemplate`.

**[edit.chtml]** try something like:

```
@model AttributeListViewModel

@foreach (var att in Model.Attributes)
{
  @Html.EditorFor(m => att)
}
```

I don't think this exact answer will work (I'm not on a machine with VS atm), but it lets you understand the problem you have.